# Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid: Is there a way to disable the "Leave Message" button in the lock screen page?

Tags: lock-screen

Is there a way to disable the "Leave Message" button feature in the lock screen?

I'd appreciate any tips and/or updates to change this to an optional feature.

Thank you!

Scott

Answer (score 2):

You could update to Oneiric (Gnome 3) where that feature has been removed, or just set auth-note-button's visible property to False in /usr/share/gnome-screensaver/lock-dialog-default.ui according to this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1798885

There are a couple of special cases in which you'll change the same setting but in a different file: if you have a theme installed or if you want to control the setting for individual users.